# Create a list of items from object's items

Tags: python-2.7, list

I have a list of objects, each of which has a list of things. I wish to create a list of the things held in all of the objects. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
class Holder(object):
    def __init__(self, things):
        self.things = things

holder_one= Holder([1, 2])
holder_two = Holder(['a', 'b'])

holders = [holder_one, holder_two]

all_things = []
for holder in holders:
    for thing in holder.things:
        all_things.append(thing)
print all_things
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

1. Make `Holder` inherit from `list` then this becomes pretty trivial.
2. Use `extend` instead of `append`, which will save you an explicit loop:

   ```
   all_things = []
   for holder in holders:
       all_things.extend(holder.things)
   print all_things
   ```

Comment: thanks, but the real Holder class will do far more than just hold a list. The example was much simplified for the purposes of the question and it would not be practicable for Holder to inherit list